# Use special characters into getElementByID

Tags: javascript, function

I have a javascript function and I want to pull data with getElementByID but every time it runs I need to pull another data how can I do that. It needs to pull another element of a list each time

```
     dotlist = [dot1,dot2,dot3]
     document.getElementById("dot1").style.backgroundColor = "#ad6e1b";
```

when the function runs it should be dot2 then 3 and then 1 again

I try this

```
    var i = 0;

    function(){
    if(i<=3)
    document.getelementbyID("dot"+i);
    i++
    else{
    i=0;
    document.getelementbyID("dot1")
    }
    }
```

but not working.

Comment: The method is [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) - watch your spelling/syntax.

Comment: There's likely an error in your console indicating that `getElementByID` is not a function.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by "pull another element of a list each time".  You seem to be on the right track, if all the elements have ids like `dot1`, `dot2`, `dot3` etc. already.  On the other hand, you may want to find all the children of a particular parent element and then iterate over that collection or use any of a multitude of queries that would select the entire set of elements you want to iterate, perhaps by class or some other semantics other than the id.  You should use the hierarchical structure of the DOM to your advantage.

Comment: Also "not working" is _never_ a sufficiently detailed description of what went wrong when you tried to do something.  Please list your expected vs actual results, and any actual error messages you encountered, hopefully with a complete, but minimal way of reproducing the problem for ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do that, here are a couple of ideas:

```js
//
// Idea 1 (if you want to define the ids on an array)
//

// Define the ids on an array
const dotList = ["dot1", "dot2", "dot3"];

// The forEach will loop through the items on the dotList array
// On each loop the current element will have the name "dotId"
dotList.forEach((dotId) => {
  // Get the element with the current id and save it into a variable called "myDotElelment"
  const myDotElement = document.getElementById(dotId);
  // Do whatever you need to the element
  console.log('idea 1:', myDotElement);
})



//
// Idea 2 (if you want to get the items directly
//

// Get all the elements which have an id starting with "dot"
const dotListTwo = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=dot]");

// Loop through the elements
// On each loop the current element will have the name "dotElement
dotListTwo.forEach((dotElement) => {
  // Do whatever you need to the element
  console.log('idea 2:', dotElement);
})
```

```html
<div id="dot1" class="dot">Dot 1</div>
<div id="dot2" class="dot">Dot 2</div>
<div id="dot3" class="dot">Dot 3</div>
```

Comment: thank you but what is el ?

Comment: `el` is just a name a chose for the variable in which we save each of the elements. You could name it whatever you want, for instance `const myElement = document.getElementById(dotId)`

Comment: @alierginn I have added some comments to my code example to try to explain what is going on...